# How to construct nested JSON in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, json

Environment:
I have data stored in SQL2000 database and I am using VWD to maintain our company website.
In the past I use asp.net + SQL database as the interface for various department until I met Json.NET.

Business Process:
Here is what I want to realize. I have several tables in our SQL database, from which I can query the project tasks, assignments... based on the users' selection or input in my aspx webpage. I would like to serialize the dataset into JSON for further processing (in a word, it could be visualized in the form as gantt chart in the webpage).

Here below is the JSON example:

```
{"tasks":[
    {"id":-1,"name":"Gantt editor","code":"","level":0,"status":"STATUS_ACTIVE","start":1346623200000,"duration":16,"end":1348523999999,"startIsMilestone":true,"endIsMilestone":false,"assigs":[]},
    {"id":-2,"name":"coding","code":"","level":1,"status":"STATUS_ACTIVE","start":1346623200000,"duration":10,"end":1347659999999,"startIsMilestone":false,"endIsMilestone":false,"assigs":[],"description":"","progress":0},
    ],
"selectedRow":0,
"deletedTaskIds":[],
"canWrite":true,
"canWriteOnParent":true }
```

In order to do so, I first construct the class based on the JSON format above. Here below is what I wrote:

```
   public class ganttData
    {
        public class Tasks
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string code { get; set; }
            public int level { get; set; }
            public string status { get; set; }
            public object start { get; set; }
            public int duration { get; set; }
            public object end { get; set; }
            public bool startIsMilestone { get; set; }
            public bool endIsMilestone { get; set; }
            public List<object> assigs { get; set; }
            public string description { get; set; }
            public int? progress { get; set; }
            public string depends { get; set; }
        }
        public int selectedRow { get; set; }
        public List<object> deletedTaskIds { get; set; }
        public bool canWrite { get; set; }
        public bool canWriteOnParent { get; set; }
    }
```

The reason why I want to construct the class is that I would like to have a test first and see if the program could work or not.
But it seems it doesn't work out.

For sure you master have better ways to do so but this is the best way that I could come out with after many times of failure attemps.

Current Status:
So far I could successfully retrieve the SQL Table Data as dataset but I don't know how to serialize the retrieved data into JSON.
Millions of thanks for your help.

Schumann

Here below is the code in my ***.aspx.cs file.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IO;
using System.Configuration;

public partial class Test_JNetToFile : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public class ganttData
    {
        public class Tasks
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string code { get; set; }
            public int level { get; set; }
            public string status { get; set; }
            public object start { get; set; }
            public int duration { get; set; }
            public object end { get; set; }
            public bool startIsMilestone { get; set; }
            public bool endIsMilestone { get; set; }
            public List<object> assigs { get; set; }
            public string description { get; set; }
            public int? progress { get; set; }
            public string depends { get; set; }
        }
        //public List<Task> tasks { get; set; }
        public int selectedRow { get; set; }
        public List<object> deletedTaskIds { get; set; }
        public bool canWrite { get; set; }
        public bool canWriteOnParent { get; set; }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ////get the connection string from web.config
        ////uncomment the following if you need to access sql database
        ////---------------------------------- Database connection----------------------------------------------
        //string connString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ShipmentConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        //DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

        //using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
        //{
        //    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        //    adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from Gantt where Nr < 5", conn);
        //    conn.Open();
        //    adapter.Fill(dataSet);
        //}  

        //string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataSet, Formatting.Indented);
        ////---------------------------------- Database connection----------------------------------------------

        ganttData gd = new ganttData
        {

            Tasks = 
            {
                {id = -1,name = "Gantt editor","code":"","level":0,"status":"STATUS_ACTIVE","start":1346623200000,"duration":16,"end":1348523999999,"startIsMilestone":true,"endIsMilestone":false,"assigs":[]},
                {id = -2,name = "coding","code":"","level":1,"status":"STATUS_ACTIVE","start":1346623200000,"duration":10,"end":1347659999999,"startIsMilestone":false,"endIsMilestone":false,"assigs":[],"description":"","progress":0},
                {id = -3,name = "gant part","code":"","level":2,"status":"STATUS_ACTIVE","start":1346623200000,"duration":2,"end":1346795999999,"startIsMilestone":false,"endIsMilestone":false,"assigs":[],"depends":""},
                {id = -4,name = "editor part","code":"","level":2,"status":"STATUS_SUSPENDED","start":1346796000000,"duration":4,"end":1347314399999,"startIsMilestone":false,"endIsMilestone":false,"assigs":[],"depends":"3"},
                {id = -5,name = "testing","code":"","level":1,"status":"STATUS_SUSPENDED","start":1347832800000,"duration":6,"end":1348523999999,"startIsMilestone":false,"endIsMilestone":false,"assigs":[],"depends":"2:5","description":"","progress":0},
                {id = -6,name = "test on safari","code":"","level":2,"status":"STATUS_SUSPENDED","start":1347832800000,"duration":2,"end":1348005599999,"startIsMilestone":false,"endIsMilestone":false,"assigs":[],"depends":""},
                {id = -7,name = "test on ie","code":"","level":2,"status":"STATUS_SUSPENDED","start":1348005600000,"duration":3,"end":1348264799999,"startIsMilestone":false,"endIsMilestone":false,"assigs":[],"depends":"6"},
                {id = -8,name = "test on chrome","code":"","level":2,"status":"STATUS_SUSPENDED","start":1348005600000,"duration":2,"end":1348178399999,"startIsMilestone":false,"endIsMilestone":false,"assigs":[],"depends":"6"}
            },
            selectedRow = 0,
            deletedTaskIds = [],
            canWrite = true,
            canWriteOnParent = true 
        };

        // serialize JSON to a string and then write string to a file
        File.WriteAllText(@"c:\movie.json", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(movie));

        // serialize JSON directly to a file
        using (StreamWriter file = File.CreateText(@"c:\movie.json"))
        {
            JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
            serializer.Serialize(file, movie);
        }


        //Label1.Text = json;
    }
}
```

Comment: http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/SerializingJSON.htm - here you can find information how you can use JSON.NET to serialize your data.

Comment: Hallo Michal, thanks for replying but I am actually using the link to learn it now. Perhaps I am not yet understanding how these things work. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Copy your JSON sample to clipboard. Open a new class file, then under the Edit menu, choose "Paste Special" then choose "Paste JSON and Classes" and you will get a class structure capable of holding the JSON you want. (assuming you are using VS 2012 and above)